# What firewall settings need to be used to block Microsoft Telemetry (spyware)?

Tags: firewall, router, blocking

I'm seeing a lot of products, such as SQL Server, coming out with opt-out spyware. This is marketed as "Telemtry" or "Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP)".

- [Can I disable the spyware in SQL Server 2017?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187093/2639)

Obviously, this can currently be disabled in the software itself. What settings on the firewall can I take to block this kind of communication with Microsoft (ip/port) blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can block

```
vortex.data.microsoft.com
tempuri.org
```

You can see that's what they're communicating to in the client-side telemetry with [`mssql-cli`](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=vortex.data.microsoft.com&type=), and [`vscode-extension-telemtry`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-telemetry/blob/master/src/telemetryReporter.ts#L71). And, [for SQL Server, you can find out how to turn them off on the client and server here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187094/2639)